# Where to find native libraries for JRE?

Tags: java, linux, windows, jakarta-mail, native

How can I find the native files (on Linux, probably a SO file, on Windows, probably a DLL) the JRE is using for making system-level calls?

How can I find the source code for these files?

**BONUS:** I'm specifically looking for the native file that JavaMail (reference impl, not GNU) is using to send SMTP/email traffic from. My *guess* is that its just implementing SMTP over TCP, so probably whatever the `java.net.URLConnection`'s `streamHandler` is using.

But, regardless of JavaMail, I'd still like to know how/where to find these files. They *must* be embedded somewhere in the JRE, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only when there is a native library in use (in your example, SMTP; it's probably implemented in pure Java). The usual way to add a native library is by using the correct flag with the java command line. For example,

```
java -Djava.library.path=%STARTPATH%\lib -jar somefile.jar
```

Comment: Thanks @Elliott Frisch (+1) - but either I totally don't understand  Java or what you are saying doesn't answer my question! I'm sure (though I can't verify) that JavaMail implements SMTP in Java, but ultimately, to send bytes onto the wire (so, TCP traffic?) it has to make native calls. **Right?!?** And if so, I need to find out what file these native calls are stored in. Like I said, on linux these are probably shared object (SO) files, and on Windows, DLLs.

Comment: So, in the case of JavaMail, I need SO/DLL that is being used to send emails over the wire. And, more generally, I'd like to know where all the native libraries are stored that are called by JRE classes.

Comment: You want to know where the native code that implements the JRE is? Because that's what you seem to be asking. The JRE itself implements the necessary portions for network socket [communication](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/), it does not do this through JNI or third party native libraries; it's directly built into the (usually) C++ code that the JRE is written in. From that link, The java.net package provides two classes--Socket and ServerSocket--that implement the client side of the connection and the server side of the connection, respectively.

Comment: Ahh yes,good point @Elliott Frisch (+1 again). However, at some point in the `Socket` (client-side) class, there has to be a call to native code. I was under the impression that this native code would come in the form of independent SO/DLL libraries. But, as you say, it is handled in the JVM itself. So I guess I would need to see the source code for my JRE's native JVM?

Comment: There is an implementation (from OpenJDK) that is annotated [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/Socket.java).

Comment: Thanks again @Elliott Frisch (+1) - Where in that link does it show bytes getting sent over the wire?

Comment: Bytes are sent over the wire through an [OutputStream](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/Socket.java#Socket.getOutputStream%28%29).

Comment: Thanks again @Elliott Frisch (+1) - but I think I'm talking about one thing, and you think I mean something else. `Socket`, `SocketServer`, `OutputStream`, these are all **Java** classes. Ultimately, they have to call **native** (Linux/Windows/systems) code somewhere, and its this *native* code that actually communicates with the machine's network card. I had *thought* this native code was in separate SO/DLL libs, but according to you, this native code resides in the JVM itself (C/C++).

Comment: So I'm asking if I need to look at this C/C++ code to find the native calls that `Socket`/`SocketServer`/`OutputStream` are calling at the Java layer. Is this correct?

Comment: The native code is in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386 (for example).  There's a whole bunch of .so files that are called by the JDK to access system calls.  What is the problem you're trying to solve and how does this help you solve that problem?